# Invalid unit argument for Intl.NumberFormat() with electric units (volt, joule...)

Tags: javascript, localization

I am trying to localize my web application and I cannot manage to make Intl.NumberFormat work with electric units (ampere, ohm, volt, joule...).

In the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat), they provide some examples and the [list of units available](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-general.html#Example_Units).

Though I cannot manage to make it work with the electric units:

```js
// Working
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('fr', { style: 'unit', unit: 'second' }).format(1000));

// Failing with Invalid unit argument for Intl.NumberFormat() 'volt'
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('fr', { style: 'unit', unit: 'volt' }).format(1000));
```

Does someone have an idea why?

Comment: `"volt"` is not [a supported unit](https://tc39.es/proposal-unified-intl-numberformat/section6/locales-currencies-tz_proposed_out.html#sec-issanctionedsimpleunitidentifier)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From MDN INTL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat)

> A [subset](https://tc39.es/proposal-unified-intl-numberformat/section6/locales-currencies-tz_proposed_out.html#sec-issanctionedsimpleunitidentifier) of units from the full list was selected for use in ECMAScript.

```
Simple Unit
-----------
acre
bit
byte
celsius
centimeter
day
degree
fahrenheit
fluid-ounce
foot
gallon
gigabit
gigabyte
gram
hectare
hour
inch
kilobit
kilobyte
kilogram
kilometer
liter
megabit
megabyte
meter
mile
mile-scandinavian
milliliter
millimeter
millisecond
minute
month
ounce
percent
petabyte
pound
second
stone
terabit
terabyte
week
yard
year
```

> Pairs of simple units can be concatenated with "-per-" to make a compound unit. There is no default value; if the style is "unit", the unit property must be provided.

Cool: *Megabytes per second* becomes *mégaoctets par seconde* in French

```js
console.log(
  new Intl.NumberFormat('fr', 
    { style: 'unit', unit: 'megabyte-per-second', 'unitDisplay': 'long' }
).format(1000)
);
```

Comment: unit
The unit to use in unit formatting, Possible values are core unit identifiers, defined in UTS #35, Part 2, Section 6. A subset of units from the full list was selected for use in ECMAScript. Pairs of simple units can be concatenated with "-per-" to make a compound unit. There is no default value; if the style is "unit", the unit property must be provided.